# iframe closing java selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, iframe

I am having some issues closing this iframe. its in the bottom of the page.

Need gift ideas or styling advice?


    Need gift ideas or styling advice?
                
        





            
        
    
            
       
        Need gift ideas
 or styling advice?
        Need gift ideas
 or styling advice?
      
    
    
        
        Huntington Station
    
    
        Start a conversation
        
    
            
        Know a Style Advisor? Search now

its asking for email, i tried to close it using windowhandle and iframe loop, but no luck.

```
  int size = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size();

  for(int i = 0;i<=size;i++) {
      driver.switchTo().frame(i);
      System.out.println("Number of frames: "+size+"of "+i);
      //driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='close-button']")).click();
      //can not find element
  }
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways you can get this `IFRAME`. One is that it's inside a `DIV` that has an ID, `generic-modal`, so you can use a CSS selector. The code below should work.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#generic-modal > iframe")));
driver.findElement(By.id("close-button")).click();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the iframes have Ids. You can switch to the iframe directly by locating them by Id.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("destination_publishing_iframe_hudsonbaycompany_0")));
driver.findElement(By.id("closeButton"));
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

And at the bottom of page , the email asking dialog is at the top frame. Could not locate any iframe around it.